# How to find the smallest value in a multi-layered python dictionary, along with "path" to it (i.e. list of keys to the leaf value)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python dictionary of the following format:

```
d = 
{
  'category' :
  {
    'genre': <int_value>
  }
}
```

I would like to find the smallest `<int_value>`, along with the "path" to it in the original dictionary.

E.g. If

```
d = 
{
  'free':
  {
    'adventure' : 23,
    'arcade' : 101,
  },
  'paid':
  {
    'arcade' : 130,
  }
}
```

...the result should be `("free", "adventure", 23)`.

Can anyone think of a one-liner for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dict` is a builtin name, I changed it to `d`

Comment: does this only need to work for the example?

Comment: I was looking for a solution that applied to an arbitrary number of levels of depth in the dictionary, just in case I need to modify its structure.

Comment: just note that the answer you accepted only works for one layer

Answer (score 5):

```
print min((d[c][x], c, x) for c in d for x in d[c])
```

and to re-arrange:

```
print min( (d[c][x], x, c) for c in d for x in d[c] )[::-1]
```

Comment: I dig it, even though it returns (23, 'free', 'adventure') :P

Comment: I'd get rid of the brackets to turn that list comprehension into a generator. Also, you can add `[::-1]` at the end to flip that resulting tuple around.

Comment: sweet, very succinct solution!

Answer (score 3):

You could write a generator that recursively yields all of the possible paths:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {
  'free': {
    'adventure' : 23,
    'arcade' : 101,
  },
  'paid': {
    'arcade' : 130,
  }
}

def get_paths(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for path in get_paths(value):
                yield (key,) + path
        else:
            yield (key, value)

print min(get_paths(d), key=itemgetter(-1))
```

Although this may be a little overkill, as your dictionary isn't nested arbitrarily deep.

Comment: Wow, exactly the same solution as me (Also works for any number of layers) +1

Answer (score 3):

This works for the given dictionary (only works for dictionaries with the same nesting level though):

```
>>> min(((k, k2, v) for k, dct in d.items() for k2, v in dct.items()), key=lambda i: i[-1])
('free', 'adventure', 23)
```

Or an alternative solution:

```
>>> min((v, k2, k) for k, dct in d.items() for k2, v in dct.items())[::-1]
('free', 'adventure', 23)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is usually the best one:

```
def find_smallest(d):
    result = None, None, float('inf')
    for category in d:
        for genre, value in d[category].items():
            if value < result[2]:
                result = category, genre, value
    return result
```

Comment: You're right, it's a solution to the problem you actually asked.

Comment: I didn't ask it but I'm not sure if OP wants that feature or not

Comment: it would be nice to get a solution that works for an arbitrary number of layers, but this solution does satisfy the stated requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to solve this with a recursive function. It's not a one-liner, but still pretty simple:

```
def min_int_value(nested_dict):
    min_path = None
    min_value = float("inf")

    for k, v in nested_dict.items(): # use iteritems() in Python 2
        path = [k]
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            p, v = min_int_value(v)
            path += p

        if v < min_value:
            min_path = path
            min_value = v

    return min_path, min_value
```